# How to import a screen class in another python file?

Tags: python, kivy, screen

I am building a kivy application and i am using ScreenManager to go from one window to another. The program is working if i have all the classes used in the screenmanager in the same python file, like this:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Login(name='login'))
sm.add_widget(Account(name='create_account'))
sm.add_widget(AfterLogin(name='after_login'))
```

But I want to have for each class a separate python file. How can I import the classes and make the screenmanager worK? i have tried to create "login_after.py" having for now only template:

```
class AfterLogin(Screen):
    pass
```

And importing the class like this:

```
import login_after
sm.add_widget(login_after.AfterLogin(name='after_login'))
```

but this triggers the following error:

```
 AttributeError: module 'login_after' has no attribute 'AfterLogin'
```

How to solve  this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work?

```py
from login_after import AfterLogin
sm.add_widget(AfterLogin(name='after_login'))
```

Comment: this works, but the thing is that it makes me import AfterLogin only in the method which uses it, not on top level python file. Can this be considered an error?

Comment: @iulianaiuliana You must import it at the top of the file in which it will be used. Its a Python thing ;o)

Comment: @iulianaiuliana If you can import only in a function/method, but not at the top of the file, then it sounds like a circular import. Do you also import the main file in `login_after` perhaps?

Comment: yes, the problem was that i was importing the whole python file, not only the used class. And in the other python file i was importing the first file, too. Thanks for noting the problem!

Comment: @moro_92 If you found my answer helpful, then you might consider to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), so other people see it too.. ;o)